# Скачать картинку C#

Tags: c#, captcha

Здравствуйте, есть [ссылка](https://c.mail.ru/c/6) где находиться картинка, но скачать ее не получаеться

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
Uri uri = new Uri("https://c.mail.ru/c/6");
client.DownloadFileAsync(uri, "picture.jpg");
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(Image.FromFile("picture.jpg"));
```

Скачивал как `jpg`, `png` и `bmp`. Не помогало. Помогите скачать картинку!

**UPD** Заменил     `client.DownloadFileAsync(uri, "picture.jpg");` на     `client.DownloadFile(uri, "picture.jpg");`
 Теперь 404

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно скачивать картинку как массив байт:

```
var str == //ссылка
byte[] photobytes = null;
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    imagebytes = client.DownloadData(str);
}
```

И получать BitmapImage из этого массива с помощью метода:

```
public static BitmapImage LoadImage(byte[] imageData)
{
    if (imageData == null || imageData.Length == 0) return null;
    var image = new BitmapImage();
    using (var mem = new MemoryStream(imageData))
    {
        mem.Position = 0;
        image.BeginInit();
        image.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat;
        image.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
        image.UriSource = null;
        image.StreamSource = mem;
        image.EndInit();
    }
    image.Freeze();
    return image;
}
```

Т.е. как-то так:

```
var str == //ссылка
byte[] imagebytes = null;
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    imagebytes = client.DownloadData(str);
}
var image = LoadImage(imagebytes);
```

**UPD:**
mail.ru возвращает 404 если не задан user-agent. 
Нужно добавить его для WebClient:

```
client.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36");
```

И весь код должен выглядеть так:

```
var str = //ссылка;
byte[] imagebytes = null;
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    client.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36");
    imagebytes = client.DownloadData(str);
}
var image = LoadImage(imagebytes);
```

или

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36");
Uri uri = new Uri("https://c.mail.ru/c/6");
await client.DownloadFileAsync(uri, "picture.jpg");
// или
client.DownloadFile(uri, "picture.jpg");
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(Image.FromFile("picture.jpg"));
```

если хотите оставить загрузку в файл.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/iCQNyWW.png